# Variable in a variable Ansible

Tags: json, ansible

I'm trying to use a variable in a variable.

I have one JSON variable :

```
os: { 

   "centos_7_5": {
    offer: "CentOS",
    publisher: "OpenLogic",
    sku: "7.5",
    version: "latest"
    },    
   "debian_9": {
    offer: "Debian",
    publisher: "credativ",
    sku: "9",
    version: "latest"
    }
}
```

If I use

```
  - debug:
      msg: " {{ os.debian_9.offer }}"
```

The output is as desired :

```
"msg": " Debian"
```

Now, I'm trying to put the OS name in a variable (so that the variable can be in a config file) as follows :

```
desired_os: debian_9
```

I would like to do something like this :

```
- debug:
    msg: " {{ os.desired_os.offer }}"
```

But I can't find a way to make it work.
I tried some concatenation in a set_fact using `'{{ "os."~desired_os~".offer" }}'` but the output is not as desired :

```
"msg": "stuff.os.debian_9.offer"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi try use this snippet:

json

```
{
    "os": {
        "centos_7_5": {
            "offer": "CentOS",
            "publisher": "OpenLogic",
            "sku": "7.5",
            "version": "latest"
        },
        "debian_9": {
            "offer": "Debian",
            "publisher": "credativ",
            "sku": "9",
            "version": "latest"
        }
    }
}
```

playbook:

```
---

- hosts: all
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    jsonVar: "{{ lookup('file', 'j.json') | from_json }}"
    dist: "debian_9"

  tasks:

    - name: test loop
      debug: msg="{{ jsonVar['os'][dist] }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `varname[var]` notation.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    os: { 
   "centos_7_5": {
    offer: "CentOS",
    publisher: "OpenLogic",
    sku: "7.5",
    version: "latest"
    },    
   "debian_9": {
    offer: "Debian",
    publisher: "credativ",
    sku: "9",
    version: "latest"
    }
    }
    desired_os: debian_9

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: " {{ os['debian_9'].offer }}"
    - debug:
        msg: " {{ os[desired_os].offer }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the variable within double brackets.

```
- debug:
     msg: " {{ os.{{ desired_os }}.offer }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try as below

```
debug: msg= "{{os.vars[desired_os].offer}}"
```